# where packages are stored in python (trying to install dragnet)

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda

I've been struggling to install a python package called dragnet and its dawned on me just how little I understand about where packages are stored and how they are accessed in python. When I do import X in python, what steps does python take to try to import the packages?

I have anaconda installed, and it looks like many are stored in ~/anaconda/pkgs with names like "argcomplete-0.8.4-py27_0".

A bunch of other packages are in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages. Sometimes conda install X doesnt work, but pip install will (conda pip is depreciated), and in these cases packages will often end up here. Both planout and dragnet are examples of such packages.

Dragnet, however, didn't want to import even despite its presence in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages. When I go directly into the folder /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages in ipython it will import ok. I could not figure out where to put it or how to make it accessible when not in the folder though? I'd appreciate a pointer to a good tutorial or overview about packaging, package locations and importing in python.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases in which you are unable to install with anaconda, and you need to install another way, and that other way ends up with the install being not in the anaconda packages folder (lets say you end up with a new install in  /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages), a reasonable work around is the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages')
import desired_package_found_in_that_folder
```

This will force python to look in that folder for packages.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of installing packages globally use Virtualenv to create virtual environments. This will help you isolate different projects and will also make dependency and package management much easier.

Read the docs here: https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/